# Does the definition of a mean-preserving spread not imply increased variance in an underlying distribution?

Tags: stochastic-ordering

A random variable **y** is a mean preserving spread of the random variable **x** iff **y = x + e** where **e** is noise and **E(e|x)=0** (per notes [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5846/2017sp/3%20vnM.pdf)).

And yet, two random variables possessing equal means and different variances does not mean that the one with the higher variance is a mean-preserving spread of the other. I thought both sentences implied the same thing (since **e** is adding variance). Is this because **E(e|x)=0** instead of **E(e)=0**?

Comment: What implicit assumptions are you making about your two random variables?  For instance, if they are independent then evidently neither can be a mean-preserving spread of the other.